# Django renders template to URL

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

When I submit an empty file to the FileUploadForm it is therefore not valid and I return the following Response:

```
return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**This Response however results in a weird behavior, because the template content is not rendered to the HTML-page, but gets appended to the URL and yields the following Request:**

Request URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/%3C?xml%20version=%221.0%22%20?%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%20PUBLIC%20%22-//W3C//DTD%20XHTM [....]

**views.py**

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SampleUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...

    else:
        form = SampleUploadForm()

    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**upload.html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'upload_file' %}" id="file_form">
    <input type="button" id="pbutton" value="Select file.." name="pbutton">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="button_file" />
    <div id="label_wrapper">
         <label id="file_label" >No File selected...</label>
     </div>
</form>
```

Already verified TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS, TEMPLATE_LOADERS & MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES for correctness.

Comment: can you show the html in the template ?

Comment: First thing I notice is, you have input type="button" instead of "submit"